# Rails Active Resources ignore conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I have been searching a solution for this issue but in no vain. Basically, I am trying to do some searches using Active Resources eg:

```
File.find(:all, :params => {:file_name => "blah"})
```

or:

```
File.find(:all, :conditions => {:file_name => "blah"})
```

File is an Active Resource object

I expect the result to be filtered but the output is the same as `File.find(:all)`(conditions are completely ignored). Has anyone experienced a similar problem?I am using rails 3.0.7, this code is called from a web app which is talking to another API server using AR.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What about `File.find(:all, {:file_name => "blah"})` (i.e. using no `:params =>`). Also, I am assuming you mean `:file_name` and not `:filename` or some variation)

Comment: Also, just FYI, [ActiveResource has now been removed from Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f1637bf2bb00490203503fbd943b73406e043d1d).

Comment: Hi Zabba, you are correct, AR is now a gem which is included in my Gemfile. `:file_name` is the right one in my case although it could be `:filename` too since it's just a column name. To be more specific, the API app use Sequel(not Active Record). Without `:params =>` I get a nil value. This AR behaviour is kinda weird

Comment: I tried `File.find(:one, :params => {:file_name => "blah"})` which limits to only one resource but does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if i got your point. I think this should do:

```
File.where file_name: "blah"
```

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned File is an Active Resources object so Active Record querying does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same type of setup, and tons of searching in my application where large results need to get filtered - however, I have been accomplishing this using the API Server side.

So calls would look like:

```
File.find(:all, :params => {:file_name => "blah"})
```

Which would be translated into some search URL by rails:

```
http://someip:port/someurl/files/?file_name=blah
```

So the API would receive this with the file_name parameter and filter the result set based on that search, and then return those filtered results to the rails server.

I hope that at least helps in some way :)